# Python JSON load leads to Error: Connection Forcibly Closed

Tags: python, json, python-idle

**Overview**: I am calling an API with python2.7 using the urllib2 and json libraries. When I run the script I receive the following error if the results count is higher than 20:

> error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host

**Script**:

```
import json
import urllib2
import webbrowser

url = "http://poi.????.com:xxxx/k/search?name==smith&limit==30"

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
webbrowser.open(url)
data = json.load(response)

count = "count = "+str(data['count'])
print count
for i in data['results']:
        name = i['name']
        print name
```

**Expected Outcome**: I run the script, API responds with a '200 OK' status and my webbrowser.open(url) line opens the response in my browser. My IDLE shell prints the output.

**Issue**: When I use the limit parameter in the API and set it to <20 it responds as expected in my IDLE shell. However if I set limit > 20 or don't set a limit, I still get a 200 OK response, the browser populates with the results but my IDLE shell produces the 'connection was forcibly closed' error.

**Software**: I've tried this on windows 7/8 and Ubuntu 14.04. At home via VPN and at work across a wired network.

**Traceback Call in IDLE**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\userQueryService.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = json.load(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 286, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 351, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(rbufsize)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 573, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

**Traceback call in Ubuntu python shell**:

```
>>> data = json.load(response)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 43303 (char 43302)
```

Comment: What happens if you run the script from a command line, without involving Idle?

Comment: Again, it works as long as the limit is < 20. But I didn't receive the same error, this time I received --> ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 43303 (char 43302)

Comment: You should edit your answer to add the traceback for the console case.  Can you post an example with a public url that you can post, so someone can try to reproduce?  Do you have the same problem with 3.4?

Comment: Added traceback calls. The script works fine on other APIs, which makes this so confusing. At first I thought it must be the service i was calling, but the logs show all the requests and a 200 status. Very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by using the **requests** library instead of **urllib2** and **json**. I've included my code for those that have a similar issue (note I also included a exception handler):

```
import webbrowser
import requests

url = "http://poi.????.com:xxxx/k/search?name==smith&limit==30"

r = requests.get(url)

try:
    data = r.json()
    webbrowser.open(url)
    count = "count = "+str(data['count'])
    print count
    for i in data['results']:
            name = i['name']
            print name

except IOError as (errno, strerror):
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
```